# Prove intersection of open sets contain F={$\vec{x}$}, F is non-empty and non $\mathbb R ^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let F be a non-empty closed subset in $\mathbb R^n$, F is not $\mathbb R^n$. Show that if F = {$\vec{x}$}, then there exists a set of open sets {$U_i: i = 1,2,3,...$} s.t. the intersection of all $U_i$ contains the set F={$\vec{x}$} and no other points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $U_i=B(x,1/i)$ where $n$ is an integer strictly positive.